# Are Objects of own Classes possible in R?

Tags: oop, class, r, methods, constructor

I'm a R-newbie, and I was wondering if it is possible to create objects of own classes. When I read the "help(class)" it did not seem that classes like in Java are possible. I mean I want to have a class with methods, private variables and a constructor. For example it could look like this:

```
className <- class {
  # private variables
  var1 <- "standardvalue"

  var2 <- TRUE
  # Constructor
  constructor (v1, v2) {
    var1 <- v1
    var2 <- v2
  }

  # Method 1
  function sum() {
    var1 + var2
  }

  # Method 2
  function product() {
    var1 * var2
  }
}
```

In my main programm I want to create an Object of this Class and call it's functions. For example like this:

```
# Create Object
numbers <- className(10,7)

# Call functions of the Object
numbers -> sum()      # Should give "17"
numbers -> product()  # Should give "70"
```

Is something like this possible? So far I did not fine any example.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: The [Object Orientation](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.html#Object-orientation) section of the Introduction to R manual refers you to the [R Language Definition](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-lang.html) manual.  [Section 5](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-lang.html#Object_002doriented-programming) discusses Object-oriented programming.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there are (at least) three OO systems to choose from in base R:

- S3
- S4
- ReferenceClasses

plus additional OO-like frameworks contributed via CRAN packages such as proto.

Please do some googling for S3, S4, ReferenceClasses, OO, ..., possibly starting at [rseek.org](http://rseek.org).  All R programming books cover this too; my favourite is Chambers (2008) book titled "Software for Data Analysis".

Comment: Apart from reference classes which are too new for any book yet (as far as I know). The built in documentation is good though.

Answer (score 0):

If you come from `java` and therefore are used to `private` and `public` attributes and methods I'd advise you to use the `R6` package. See this [link](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/R6/vignettes/Introduction.html).  A trivial example of a person class taken from the documentation is this:

```
library(R6)
Person <- R6Class("Person",
  public = list(
    name = NA,
    hair = NA,
    initialize = function(name, hair) {
      if (!missing(name)) self$name <- name
      if (!missing(hair)) self$hair <- hair
      self$greet()
    },
    set_hair = function(val) {
      self$hair <- val
    },
    greet = function() {
      cat(paste0("Hello, my name is ", self$name, ".\n"))
    }
  )
)
```

Here's how you can create an instance of this class:

```
johnDoe <- Person$new("John Doe")
johnDoe$set_hair("brown")
```

Note that unlike `java` methods are invoked using the `$` operator after the object.